# Query Doesn't Match Numbers In Text

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Match queries can find strings that contain numbers, in this case, I am trying to search matching phone numbers. Mappings and analyzers are provided below. For example, I have an index as follows

```
{
  "userId": 126817,
  "name": "Test User",
  "phoneNumber": "5551112233",
}
```

When I use match query doesn't match anything

```
{"match" : {"phoneNumber": {"query": "555"}}}
```

When I use prefix value it does match

```
{"prefix" : {"phoneNumber": {"value ": "555"}}}
```

Analyze Results

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "5551112233",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Mapping

```
{
      index: "user-clinics",
      type: "user-clinic",
      body: {properties: {id: {type: "long"}} }
}
```

Analyzers

```
const TurkishAnalyzer = {
  analysis: {
    filter: {
      my_ascii_folding: {
        type: "asciifolding",
        preserve_original: true
      }
    },
    analyzer: {
      turkish_analyzer: {
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase", "my_ascii_folding"]
      }
    }
  }
};

const AutoCompleteAnalyzer = {
  analysis: {
    filter: {
      autocomplete_filter: {
        type: "edge_ngram",
        min_gram: 1,
        max_gram: 20
      }
    },
    analyzer: {
      autocomplete_search: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase"]
      },
      autocomplete_index: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase", "autocomplete_filter"]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Match query doesn't work when queried with numbers.  For "asd123" string if I query "asd" I find the
"rows": [
        {
            "_index": "user-clinics",
            "_type": "user-clinic",
            "_id": "126817",
            "_score": 1.6943598,
            "_source": {
                "userClinicId": 126817,
                "name": "Test Test",
                "phoneNumber": "asd123",
                "clinicId": 1,
            }
        }
    ]

If I query "123" the result is 
"rows": []

Answer (score 0):

It's because `edge_ngram` tokenizes only from the beginning of the token, hence all prefixes will be indexed, i.e. `a`, `as`, `asd`, `asd1`, `asd12`, `asd123`

You need to change your `autocomplete_filter` to `ngram` if you also want to be able to match inside tokens, i.e. `d12` or `123`.

Beware, though, that this might generate a lot more tokens

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Changed autocomplete_filter to 
type: "ngram",
min_gram: 1,
max_gram: 2

Still "d1" does not match "asd123"

Comment: min_ngram should be at least 2 (or even 3) and max_ngram needs to be bigger than 2 otherwise you will never have `123` as a token